# PyTorchでのNLP_RNNにて、CPU GPU混在エラー

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pytorch

PyTorchのまだ初心者ですが、NLPのシンプルなRNN構築を目指しております。
CPUでは動くのですが、デバイスをGPUにするとCPU、GPUの混在エラーが解消できません。
hidden層あたりが原因と考えてるのですが、どうやっても解消できず。
どなたか助言をいただけますと助かります。

## RNNクラス

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, emb_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.emb = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_size)
    self.rnn = nn.RNN(emb_size, hidden_size, nonlinearity='tanh', batch_first=True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

  def forward(self, x):
    self.batch_size = x.size()[0]
    hidden = self.init_hidden()
    emb = self.emb(x)
    out, hidden = self.rnn(emb, hidden)
    out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
    return out

  def init_hidden(self):
    hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)
    return hidden
```

上記で、
self.to(device)
hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
などとしてみましたが、エラーが解消できません。

## device

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

## 変数

```
VOCAB_SIZE = len(word_id.keys()) +1
EMB_SIZE = 300
OUTPUT_SIZE = 4
HIDDEN_SIZE = 50
model = RNN(VOCAB_SIZE,EMB_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE)
model = model.to(device)
```

## 予測

```
for i in range(10):
  # datasetet　の、リスト０indexに入力要素
  X, y = dataset_train[i]
  X = X.to(device)
  print(torch.softmax(model(X.unsqueeze(0)), dim=1))
```

上記のコードは、CPUでは動きましたが、to(device)で、modelとデータを送ったところ、CPUとGPUの混在エラーが出てしまいます。

## エラーメッセージ

```
Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and hidden tensor at cpu
```

原因となる箇所を、ご指摘いただけますと幸甚です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

時間も経過しており既に解決済みかもしれませんが，Google Colab (python 3.8.16, torch 1.13.0+cu116) を使って下記の記述例で確認する限りでは

```
        # hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)
        hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
```

の変更でエラーは発生しなくなりました。なお，`train.txt` は[【python】言語処理100本ノック2020を解く(第9章前半)](https://mori-memo.hateblo.jp/entry/2022/10/16/173011) を基に作らせていただきました。

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import torch
from torch import nn


class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, emb_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.emb = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_size)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(emb_size, hidden_size, nonlinearity='tanh',
                          batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.batch_size = x.size()[0]
        hidden = self.init_hidden()
        emb = self.emb(x)
        out, hidden = self.rnn(emb, hidden)
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out

    def init_hidden(self):
        # hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)
        hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        return hidden

def tokenizer(txt):
    ws = txt.rstrip().split()
    return [word_id.get(w, 0) for w in ws]


# device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# read data
train = pd.read_csv('train.txt', sep='\t')

# dictionary for tokenizer()
words = []
for text in train['TITLE']:
    for word in text.rstrip().split():
        words.append(word)
c = Counter(words)
word_id = {}
for i, cnt in enumerate(c.most_common()):
    if cnt[1] > 1:
        word_id[cnt[0]] = i + 1

# dataset_train
train['TTL'] = train['TITLE'].apply(tokenizer)
train['CAT'] = train['CATEGORY'].map({'b': 0, 't': 1, 'e': 2, 'm': 3})
dataset_train = []
for i in train.index:
    dataset_train.append(
        [torch.tensor(train.loc[i, 'TTL'], dtype=torch.int),
         torch.tensor(train.loc[i, 'CAT'], dtype=torch.int)])

# model
VOCAB_SIZE = len(word_id.keys()) + 1
EMB_SIZE = 300
OUTPUT_SIZE = 4
HIDDEN_SIZE = 50
model = RNN(VOCAB_SIZE, EMB_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE).to(device)

# initial prediction
for i in range(5):
    X, y = dataset_train[i]
    X = X.to(device)
    print(torch.softmax(model(X.unsqueeze(0)), dim=1))
```

```
tensor([[0.2418, 0.2491, 0.3167, 0.1924]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)
tensor([[0.3865, 0.1211, 0.3834, 0.1089]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)
tensor([[0.1702, 0.3075, 0.3873, 0.1349]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)
tensor([[0.3631, 0.1873, 0.1873, 0.2623]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)
tensor([[0.3344, 0.2631, 0.2306, 0.1719]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)
```

Comment: 遅くなり申し訳ありません。回答誠にありがとうございます。大変助かります。またご指摘いただいた通り、私も１００本ノックのRNN編でのつまずきがきっかけでの投稿でした。誠にありがとうございます。